# Strongloop Loopback: where filter with two arrays

Tags: arrays, node.js, where-clause, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to add a where filter in strongloop / loopback which compares two different arrays.

I have the following model:

```
"properties": {
  ...
  "audience": {
    "type": [
      "string"
    ],
  ...  
}
```

I want to create a where clause which returns all items where at least one element from 'audience' matches at least one element of another array.

Examples with `"audience": ["A", "B", "C"]`

- "anotherArray": ["A", "Z"] => should match!
- "anotherArray": ["A", "B"] => should match!
- "anotherArray": ["B"] => should match!
- "anotherArray": ["Z", "Y"] => should not match!
- "anotherArray": ["Z"] => should not match!

The filter `{where: { audience: { inq: anotherArray}}};` does not seem to do the trick...

Comment: It should work. What is your database?

Comment: I'm using mongodb. It doesn't work with audience as array.

Comment: Absolutely it should work. Maybe the issue is from another place. Maybe a scope,... . Please share some more code if you can

Comment: It's because of loopback version. In version `3.x` this is solved

Comment: It's getting quite bizarre: If the values in the arrays are "normal" strings like for example "A" or "myString" everything works as expected. But it the values are mongodb generated ids (idInjection in my model is set to true) like "58b5e047755d61040ac0b6bf" it doesn't work, i.e. an empty array is returned if it should match... Only removing the last "f" of this id is enough that it works!

Comment: Yes it's a bug in loopback and I've issued that before. In the source code they check based on regex if it is id or not

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I guess there is not much we can do about it except modifying the id string somehow. Thanks @EbrahimPasbani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work if the string values are ids. See comment of Ebrahim Pasbani above.